# have got phrase for Americans

Tags: verbs, american-english, participles

I have heard that in American English, if I say "have got", the American would think that I am not educated as it should be "have gotten", yet I heard Americans said this in lots of movies. So is the phrase "have got" ok to use for the Americans?

Comment: It will depend on a bit more context, could you please add some examples. Whether or not people will take the time to wonder if you are educated will depend on the person you are speaking to.

Comment: "I have heard that in American English, if I say "have got", the American would think that I am not educated" - where did you hear this?  I hear "have got" all the time, and it doesn't imply anything about education to me.  I mean, *I've got* a whole list of things I'm biased about, but that's not one of them.  [It is true that "have got" seems to be getting less common over time, though.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+got&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20got%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I have got to stop wasting so much time at SE.

Comment: Note: "Have got to" is a common expression meaning "I need to".

Comment: Perhaps ironically, if a foreigner used `have got` (or any of the "slang" versions of `get`), I'm usually impressed since it's such a broadly used term, but tends to be hard for foreigners to understand well I think.  But generally, "have got" is fine! (See @mkennedy's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Have got* can mean, simply, *have* (as in *possess*). This is especially true for British English (BrE). Note that with this meaning, *have got* is usually contracted to *'ve got*.

*Have got* is **also** the BrE present perfect of *get*, which in American English (AmE)  is *have gotten*.

But there's a lot of uses that crossover from North America to the UK and vice versa, so these distinctions are not as  strict as before. (Younger BrE speakers sometimes use American pronunciations of some words such as *schedule*.)

Still, in AmE we prefer *gotten* as the participle (*have gotten*, *had gotten*)  and *got* may seem "uneducated" to some Americans or even "incorrect" on a test of AmE; it depends on the test-writers. In BrE *have got*, *had got* are standard.

Comment: The "__'ve got" formulation almost always means "have", while a "gotten" form really does mean "received at some point in the past" but does not necessarily imply current possession, especially in the "had gotten" form.

Comment: I agree with Monty, the main issue with this answer is that in many cases this replacement doesn't work. If you say "I have a cold" that has a different meaning from "I've gotten a cold", it would instead be correctly changed to "I've got a cold". "gotten" implies past tense, "got" implies present tense

Comment: "In the case of *have*, especially, if one comments on the acquisition of something, the implicature is that one still has it -- otherwise, one would say something different. So the present perfect of *get* naturally implicates the present of "have", **leading to the equivalence of *have got* and *have*.**

—[John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/76141)

Comment: For me, if it's not contracted, it sounds weird/wrong... that's why mentioning it is useful. I'd say either "I've got an apple" or "I have an apple" but never "I have got an apple".

Comment: @Catija I've mentioned the contracted version now. I didn't at first because Ook specifically asks about the non-contracted form. And we certainly use it in questions ('Have you got any sevens?') and in exclamations ('Have I got some news for you!') and in emphasis ('Yes, I *have* got an apple').

Comment: The question and exclamation don't count because the word order is totally different. You can't contract words if they're backwards. I'd argue that for emphasis (personally) I'd say "Yes, I *do* have an apple."

Comment: @Catija "Don't count" towards or regarding what? The base form of the contracted form is **[have got](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84901/have-got-phrase-for-americans/84908?noredirect=1#comment164188_84908)**,  and it is used to cover all possible non-contracted and contracted forms, including the simple, non emphasized indicative statement, whether or not this last form seems weird to you.

Comment: You can only contract something in the standard form "I have" ==> "I've". You can not contract "Have I" or "Have you" into anything because the words are in the wrong order. "Have I some news for you" makes absolutely no sense at all... at least, not in modern English. "Have you any___" is OK-ish but it sounds a bit odd in AmE anyway. "Have you got any___" or "Do you have any___" is much more common.

Comment: And let's not forget the HIlaire Belloc couplet: "Whatever happens, we have got/the Maxim Gun and they have not."

Comment: @MontyHarder I agree with [your comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84901/have-got-phrase-for-americans/84908?noredirect=1#comment164133_84908) but/therefore I'm not sure why you wrote it–what in my answer called it forth?

Answer (score 11):

This question and AlanCarmack's answer has gotten me to think about when I use "have/had got" and "have/had gotten." I grew up in the USA Midwest, plus 20 years in a heterogenous southern California area.

I do use "have got" for possession, but almost always with "have" contracted, "I've got." For instance,

> "I have got a cold." / "I've got a cold."
>   "I've got a hankering for sushi."
>   "I've got blue suede shoes on."
>   "I've got $30 in my wallet."

I use "have gotten" with a sense of motion or action--at least that's how I describe it.

> "I've gotten over my cold."
>   "I've gotten into the car."
>   "I've gotten on my blue suede shoes."
>   "I've gotten $30 from Mary for the gift."

Comment: I think the main reason for this usage is that you could say, "I have a cold", but once you contract it, the sentence sounds wrong, "I've a cold", so to fix that, we put another word that makes the meaning clear again, in this case "got".

Comment: You forgot "I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts". ;)

Comment: @KevinWells and everyone, I highly suggest you read [this ELU answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/have-got-verb-form-and-tense/76141#76141) by linguistic John Lawler, who explains what lies behind *I've got a cold* and the whole issue of *have got*/*have gotten*.

Answer (score 2):

American English prefers **have gotten** over **have got** specifically in the case of using **to get** as an auxiliary verb to express the passive voice.

> verbal auxiliary
>
> used with the past participle of transitive verbs as a passive voice  auxiliary
>
> *they got caught in the act*

(copied from: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get):

In other words, when **to get** is used to mean that another action has happened to you, AmE uses **have/had gotten** and BrE uses **have/had got**

AmE:

> I *have gotten* passed on the interstate many times
>
> He *had gotten* punched.

BrE:

> I *have got* passed on the motorway many times.
>
> He *had got* punched.